# Keras with mxnet-backend and 8 GPUs trains slow when using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, mxnet

Following this great post: [Scaling Keras Model Training to Multiple GPUs](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/scaling-keras-training-multiple-gpus/) I tried to upgrade my model to run in parallel on my multiple GPUs instance.

At first I ran the MNIST example as proposed here: [MNIST in Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) with the additional syntax in the compile command as follows:

```
# Prepare the list of GPUs to be used in training
NUM_GPU = 8 # or the number of GPUs available on your machine
gpu_list = []
for i in range(NUM_GPU): gpu_list.append('gpu(%d)' % i)

# Compile your model by setting the context to the list of GPUs to be used in training.
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'], 
              context=gpu_list)
```

then I trained the model:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

So far so good. It ran for less than 1s per epoch and I was really excited and happy until I tried - **data augmentation**.

To that point, my training images were a numpy array at size (6000,1,28,28) and the labels were at size (10,60000) - one-hot encoded. For data augmentation I used the ImageDataGenerator function:

```
gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=8, width_shift_range=0.08, shear_range=0.3,
                               height_shift_range=0.08, zoom_range=0.08)
batches = gen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=NUM_GPU*64)
test_batches = gen.flow(x_test, y_test, batch_size=NUM_GPU*64)
```

and then:

```
model.fit_generator(batches, batches.N, nb_epoch=1, 
                    validation_data=test_batches, nb_val_samples=test_batches.N)
```

And unfortunately, from 1s per epoch I started getting ~11s per epoch... I suppose that the "impact" of the ImageDataGenerator is destructive and it probably running all the (reading->augmenting->writing to gpu) process really slow and inefficient.

Scaling keras to multiple GPUs is great, but data-augmentation is essential for my model to be robust enough.

I guess one solution could be: load all images from directory and write your own function that shuffles and augment those images. But I'm sure must be some easier way to optimize this process using keras API.

**Thanks!**

Comment: It is not clear what your question is, do you want a solution to speed up your preprocessing? IIRC the `ImageDataGenerator` is mostly CPU bound and does not scale its operations to GPUs. Your only option is to to your image augmentation as a layer using keras backend functions instead to benefit from the multi-GPU scaling.

Comment: Yes exactly.. I have 2 main problems: first - I don't want to load my images into a numpy array before the training so I want to use the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory function (and simultaneously to apply the data augmentation). I guess doing the data-augmentation in a manual keras layer isn't trivial, right? The question was basically whether I can force imageDataGenerator to use the GPUs

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found the solution.
You need to use mxnet's iterator. see here:
[Image IO - Loading and pre-processing images](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/basic/image_io.html)
instead of Keras's data_generator